# Comparing density estimates from two detection models of separate datasets

Tags: r, distance, t-test

I am wanting to compare the density estimates from two separate detection models of two separate datasets. Both models were ran using the ds() function in the Distance package in R. I believe I need to use a simple t-test here, but I am not sure how to compute that.

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in within the distance package, and my understanding is that bootstrapping would not be appropriate here because I am not comparing different stratums within the same dataset. I also thought I would try running an ANOVA, but found that ds models were not compatable with ANOVA.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to use bootdht() with two models based on two separate flatfiles?

Comment: Problem resolved. The package BSDA, function tsum.test, allows you to enter mean values, standard deviations, and sample sizes to run ttests. It was very user friendly